# remove duplicates without using remove or fromkeys;list slicing; python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicates in a list with iteration and slicing (without `.remove` or `fromkeys` etc) and keep having wrong result.

For example now I have a list `['a', 'n', 'a', 'a', 'n']` and by running the following code I keep getting `['a', 'a', 'n']`

```
for i in range(1, len(lst)-1):
  if lst[i] == lst[0]:
    lst = lst[1:]
return lst
```

I think this is the cause: when there are three elements in the list the range becomes `range(1, 2)` which contains nothing. But even when I change it to

```
for i in range(len(lst)-1)
```

which in my opinion makes no sense and should just remove all the elements leaving only the last one `['n']`, it still returns `['a', 'a', 'n']`

Does anyone know the explanation to this? Why does it seem stuck in this step?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists

Answer (score 3):

You could just put the new elements into a new `list` like,

```
>>> x
['a', 'n', 'a', 'a', 'n']
>>> y = []
>>> 
>>> for e in x:
...   if e not in y:
...     y.append(e)
... 
>>> y
['a', 'n']
```

or just,

```
>>> list(set(x))
['n', 'a']
```